# WPF, C#, MVVM Notify ViewModel dynamically in changes from static vars in Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have **ViewModel** that makes some functions. Funcs are initiate by button, i have command on button click.

**`ViewModel.cs`**

```
class WindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public WindowViewModel()
    {
        canExecute = true;
    }

    public ICommand ApplyKMMCommand //command for button click, works great, tested
    {
        get
        {
            return applyKMMCommand ?? (applyKMMCommand = new Commands.CommandHandler(() => 
                                                       ApplyKMMToNewImage(), canExecute));
        }
    }

    private bool canExecute;
    private ICommand applyKMMCommand;

    public void ApplyKMMToNewImage()
    {
        ApplyKMM.Init(); //algorithm name
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public BitmapImage DisplayedImage //displaying image that i work with
    {
        get { return Bitmaps.Filepath; }
        set { Bitmaps.Filepath = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayedImage)); }
    }
}
```

Now, my **`ApplyKMM.Init()`**

```
class ApplyKMM
{

    public static void Init()
    {
        Bitmaps.Filepath = //do some thing with it...
    }
}
```

And my **`Models.Bitmaps.cs`**

```
    static public BitmapImage Filepath
    {
        get { return filepath; }
        set { filepath = value; }
    }

    static private BitmapImage filepath{ get; set; }
```

The problem is, when i make `ApplyKMM.Init` the `Image` control that is binded to View not change their value.

Without `ApplyKMM` i can do in ViewModel that thing:

```
DisplayedImage = //do things with bitmap...
```

And then, `Image` that is presented in View change (after making things with that image).

Can you tell me, how to notify ViewModel, that somewhere in code `filepath` from Models changed?

**EDIT:**

Binding in `View` Looks like standard binding:

```
<Image Source="{Binding DisplayedImage}"/>
```

Button click works too, i have problem only with communication between `Models->ApplyKMM->ViewModel`

**EDIT2:**

Properties `Filepath` is storage in `Models` folder, not folder where function `ApplyKMM` is. Look into my edit, i try to make something like:

`Models -> ApplyKMM -> ViewModel`. From Models, i get `Filepath`. Then, i using function `ApplyKMM` that is in another namespace. Then, after working on bitmap with `ApplyKMM` func i want to somehow notify `ViewModel`, that work on `Model` is done (for example, convert to grayscale) and i want to show that grayscale image in VM. It works, when i want to do `Model -> ViewModel` (`ApplyKMM` is in VM class) but i want to move out `ApplyKMM` away from `ViewModel`. And that when staris starts for me.

Comment: If someone giving downvote it will be good to know why, because examples in Stack dont fit in my need and i cant rewrite it to my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like you want to notify when a static property changes. For this, you may use the `StaticPropertyChanged` event.

```
class ApplyKMM
{
    #region Properties
    static BitmapImage _Filepath;
    public static BitmapImage Filepath
    {
        get { return _Filepath; }
        set { if (_Filepath != value) { _Filepath = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Filepath)); } }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Static NotifyPropertyChanged
    public static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void NotifyAllStaticPropertyChanged()
    {
        NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }

    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
    #endregion
}
```

Please take note that this is available from WPF Version 4.5.
You might also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786519/inotifypropertychanged-for-static-variable/9786554) interesting.

Comment: This wont work in my scenerio, because properties `Filepath` is storage in `Models` folder, not folder where function `ApplyKMM` is. Look into my edit, i try to make something like:

`Models -> ApplyKMM -> ViewModel`. From Models, i get `Filepath`. Then, i using function ApplyKMM that is in another namespace. Then, after working on bitmap with `ApplyKMM` func i want to somehow notify `ViewModel`, that work on `Model` is done (for example, convert to grayscale) and i want to show that grayscale image in VM

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is not a good practice to notify changes of a static variable to an instance.

Then, let’s look at your code:

`Bitmaps` class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so when `Filepath` changes, nothing will be notified (of course, it is a static property)

In your case, you should use local variable to hold `DisplayedImages`. Then changes on `DisplayedImage` should be updated by the binding.

```
BitmapImage _displayedImage;
public BitmapImage DisplayedImage 
{
    get { return displayedImage; }
    set { displayedImage = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayedImage)); }
}
```

Comment: I know i can make it locally, but how to notify VM in that way:

`VM -> ApplyKMM -> Model`?

Comment: I dont want to store same values in VM and Model

Comment: Then you need to hold a static variable in Models.Bitmaps.cs class, and passes the instance of WindowViewModel to it. when Filepath changes, you can update DisplayedImage via the static instance. (well this is not recommanded ...)